# Preferential attachment: Selecting a node to attach

Tags: simulation, netlogo

I've been struggling with this one for the last 24 hours or so I feel like I'm missing something relatively simple here.

```
to setup-scale-free-network

   clear-all
  ;; Make a circle of turtles
  set num-nodes (num-children + num-adults + num-toddlers)
   create-children num-children
    create-adults num-adults
    create-toddlers num-toddlers 

  layout-circle turtles (max-pxcor - 8)
  ask turtles[
  create-links-with turtles with [self > myself and random-float 5 < probability]



  ]
     setup   
 end

to-report find-partner  
  report [one-of both-ends] of one-of links
end
```

The above code creates a set number of turtles of various breeds and creates a number of links between these breeds.

```
to go
  reset-ticks
   make-link find-partner 

   tick
  end
```

The two procedures would be called until the needed level of degree distribution as been met.

What I want to do is use the find-partner procedure to move towards preferential attachment to do this I need to modify this code to create a link from the node find partner has selected to one of each of the other three types of breeds in my network.

```
to make-node [old-node]
  crt 1
  [
    set color red
    if old-node != nobody
      [ create-link-with old-node [ set color green ]
        ;; position the new node near its partner
        move-to old-node
        fd 8
      ]
  ]
end
```

My own attempts have lead no where to be honest. I know I'm asking for a lot of help but I'm at my wits end here, thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: You may be trying to learn too much all at once by making a big change all at once. Start with working code; make a small change that takes you in the right direction; get that change working; attempt to make a further small improvement, and get that working; and so on. If at any point you get stuck, come here, show your code, and ask a specific question about it.

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to completely understand your question. I am guessing that you wish to create another type of link which you call preferential attachment (with green color) between turtles who are already a  part of the network.

One thing you might want in this situation is that you do not pick turtles which are already in a preferential attachment network. [this is just my assumption]

I have modified your code (as follows) to get the desired network with preferential attachment shown with green colored links, have added a turtle-variable `already-attached` which is used to exclude turtles which are already preferentially attached to others.

Hope this helps!

```
breed [ children child ]
breed [ adults adult ]
breed [ toddlers toddler ]

children-own [ already-attached ]
adults-own [ already-attached ]
toddlers-own [ already-attached ]


to setup-scale-free-network

  clear-all
  let num-children 5
  let num-adults 5
  let num-toddlers 5
  let probability 1

  ;; Make a circle of turtles

  create-children num-children [ set color orange ]
  create-adults num-adults  [ set color green ]
  create-toddlers num-toddlers  [ set color blue ]

  layout-circle turtles (max-pxcor - 8)
  ask turtles
  [
    create-links-with turtles with [self > myself and random-float 5 < probability]
  ]

end


to go
  setup-scale-free-network
  ask turtles with [already-attached = 0]
  [
    attach-to-one-of-each-breed self
  ]
end

to attach-to-one-of-each-breed [ source-node ]
  ask source-node
    [
      if any? other children with [ already-attached = 0 ] 
      [
        ask one-of other children 
        [
          set already-attached 1
          create-link-with source-node [ set color green ]
        ]
      ]

      if any? other adults with [ already-attached = 0 ] 
      [
        ask one-of other adults 
        [
          set already-attached 1
          create-link-with source-node [ set color green ]
        ]
      ]

      if any? other toddlers with [ already-attached = 0 ] 
      [
        ask one-of other toddlers 
        [
          set already-attached 1
          create-link-with source-node [ set color green ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
end
```

Comment: Minor suggestion: I'd use `true` and `false` instead of `1` and `0`.